# VB6's MSXML2.XMLHTTP vs C#'s WebResponse

Tags: c#, soap, vb6

I'm hoping someone might know the cause of my issue without my having to provide my VB6 sample, but I can add it if necessary.

I have a simple SOAP client in both C# (.NET 4.5) and in VB6. The C# code uses WebResponse to handle my request, and in VB6 I'm using MSXML2.XMLHTTP.

They both are run on the same machine, with the same user account, using the exact same service URL, the same action, the same payload, the same headers, and neither one sends any authentication information. The VB6 gets the expected response, but my C# gets an authentication error when calling WebResponse response = request.GetResponse().

I'm not sending any form of authentication with either client.

The C# code follows:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace CarryUpReport
{
    public class PricedexHttpClient
    {
        public void Send(string url, string action, string body)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(url, action);
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; // see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/908573/a-post-or-put-request-may-fail-when-you-use-the-httpwebrequest-class-t

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream stream = null;
            try
            {
                stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                // the next line throws an exception:
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (null != stream) stream.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use Wireshark or Fiddler or the like to compare the two requests being made. Please include that data in your question.

Comment: I don't think they I can. The web service runs on a client's non public server; and I likely can't install wireshark on the client's machine which I can remote desktop to.

Comment: If you can't compare the two requests, there will be much guessing involved.

Comment: So nothing obvious stands out? I'll have to ask the client if I can install wireshark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbeknownst to me the server required authentication. It seems the VB6 code was automagically passing the credentials of the logged in user. So I solved the problem by adding:

```
webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```